# Does Darth Vader still have an implanted explosive from when he was a slave?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, the-phantom-menace

In *Episode I: The Phantom Menace*, young Anakin Skywalker and his mother explain how the Tatooine slave owners prevent the slaves from escaping:

> SHMI: All slaves have a transmitter placed inside their bodies somewhere.
>
> ANAKIN: I've been working on a scanner to try and locate mine. Any attempt to escape, and they blow you up!

Anakin is eventually freed by Qui-Gon - and Watto respects the terms of the bet because he's afraid of potential retribution from the Hutts if he didn't. But there's no scene that shows or explains what happens to Anakin's implant.

**Does the adult Darth Vader still have an explosive implanted somewhere in his body?**

If so, and the Rebellion happened to discover the exact frequency or signal needed to detonate the explosive, could they remotely assassinate Darth Vader?

Comment: Does he ***STILL*** have it? How long has it been since that "long long ago"? Thousands of years, or millions?

Comment: I agree with the duplicate classification - but you can't blame me for missing the dup, given it's title :-). I'll leave this question up for search purposes, but there's no need for anyone to answer, since the dup already has one.

Comment: IMHO the other question doesn't answer it directly. It is stated that the transmitter is neutralized and the explosive should be removed later. It is quite propable that the Jedi order removed it, bu not stated directly.

Comment: It’s a transmitter? Not an explosive? That is, they can locate the slave and send a missile? Surely having explosives inside a slave isn’t a good idea (one dead slave and the others could make a bomb).